# facebook returns error 324 reuires upload file when uploaded the file from fiddler

Tags: facebook-graph-api, fiddler, photo-upload

i am trying to upload photo to facebook using fiddler

In the request builder portion specified the url as

https://graph.facebook.com/118437721597702/photos?access_token=generated token

in the request header part

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundry=AaB03xBFSI2P MIME-version: 1.0
```

in the request body

--AaB03xBFSI2P
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="message"

My photo caption

```
--AaB03xBFSI2P
```

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="source"
Content-Type: image/png

..image data..
--AaB03xBFSI2P

but it returns "requires upload file error"

Comment: How specifically did you generate your upload request? Fiddler's request builder is not presently suitable for uploading binary content.

Comment: now i am trying frmo the code. but getting the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked from the application and data was send in the winhttpsendrequest